# How to add bidirectional edge using Rexster?

Tags: graph, gremlin, titan, edges, rexster

I'm using Rexster To Create edge between two vertex using the HTTP POST Method.

```
/graphs/<graph>/edges/3?_outV=<id>&_label=friend&_inV=2&<key>=<key'>
```

I'm referring link :

[Rexster HTTP](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Basic-REST-API)

Here I need to provide out vertex (i.e _outV ) and in vertex (i.e _inV), which is a single direction edge. How can I create a bi-directional edge using Rexster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinkerPop doesn't support a bi-directional edge type as part of [Blueprints](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki) (or [TinkerPop 3.x](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/)). You'd have to simulate bi-directionality by adding the edge in the opposing direction in two separate requests.

```
/graphs/<graph>/edges/3?_outV=<id>&_label=friend&_inV=2&<key>=<key'>
/graphs/<graph>/edges/2?_outV=<id>&_label=friend&_inV=3&<key>=<key'>
```